# Concurrency Thread is running more user than the defined in the configuration

Tags: jmeter

Total Concurrency 12

Ramp Up Time (sec) 120

Ramp up step 4

In listener, sometime I have seen 17 user or sometimes 21.

I am expecting to have Total user with the group of 3

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency Thread Group is running exactly that number of users as you define in the "Target Concurrency" field, not less, not more.

Here is the demo, I only changed 120 seconds to 12 to keep it reasonably short.

[image]

I can only think of one situation when the described behaviour is possible: [running JMeter test in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter). In that case the actual load will be 12 multiplied by the number of JMeter slave machines, for example:

- 1 slave - 12 threads
- 2 slaves - 24 threads
- 3 slaves - 36 threads
- etc.

You can also check out jmeter.log file, it normally contains entries about starting and stopping threads and the reason for this, it might be the case you have more than one Thread Group or another component like [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) or custom code in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) which kicks off extra threads.

Comment: Hi , I have observed carefully and found that my threads are 12 only but they are getting repeated
i.e. 1-1,1-2,1-3,1-4,1-1(again)

is there any particular reason of this behavior?

Comment: Each thread executes Samplers upside down, when there are no more samplers to execute- the next loop starts

Comment: If you want to start next loop with a new user - set "Thread Iterations Limit" to `1`. If you want to get the current iteration number you can do this using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) like `${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}`

Comment: Thanks for explanation.
I have understood that though we have concurrency of 3 user in 30 sec but there is higher possibility that out of 3 users few of them or all 3 users have completed their transaction based on the API response. So JMeter again adding same user in the thread to maintain the 3 user concurrency and it is resulting more user transaction than the defined.

Comment: Yes setting the Thread Iteration Limit to 1 is helping to maintain exact user. As it is restricting each user to run only once.(Which seems to be more real time scenario).